# JavaFX drag in order to modify nodes

Tags: user-interface, javafx, drag-and-drop, calendar

I'm here because my research and testing lead me nowhere.

I have made a little calendar application and now I want to improve the user interface with nice controls. I'm trying to achieve an interface where you can create an event by dragging over it (as you can do in Google agenda, in fact this a school project and I want to reproduce this week view).

For this purpose I have tried this approach:
For each cells of the area (a GridPane that contain VBoxes) I attach handlers that achieve that feature (setOnDragDetected, setOnMouseDragEntered and setOnMouseDragReleased). And it does the job well but in some case this don't work (if the mouse move over another event, which do no have the handlers, the drag feature stop).

As I saw this too heavy and subject to bogus (3 handlers x 7 columns x 48 rows = 1008 handlers !! ), I thought about other approach but I'm a beginner in javaFX and I don't know if there is other mechanism to perform this. (I thought about a transparent layout/pane that will handle this feature and act like a "touch screen" over my application but I did not found satisfying answers). Can someone enlighten me about this kind of problem ? For a good example of what I try to achieve take the behaviour of the Google agenda for an event creation with the mouse (I do not need to manage overlap of event). Thanks in advance !!
I post a picture of what the actual view look like.
[image: Actual view]

Comment: I would not listen to drag events on individual cells, but on the whole GridPane and translate GridPane coordinates to cell coordinates where necessary.

Comment: Lol it seems so obvious. I'll try this !

Comment: I'd actually imagine the translation of coordinates could be tricky, and possibly expensive as (at least in principle) you'd have to test against all the "time slots" in the view. (Though I'd imagine there are some nice ways to avoid that.) On the other hand, I'm not too convinced having ~1000 handlers or so, which are basically not getting invoked very much, is that big a deal. Here's a [very simple example](https://gist.github.com/james-d/c4a2cf66efecbf3aa362), which just allows selection of a range of time slots using this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as [Tomas Mikula](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1572599/tomas-mikula) suggest me I only attached my handlers to the GridPane (and not to each "cell" as I made previously): setOnDragDetected, setOnMouseDragOver, setOnMouseDragReleased and setOnMouseDragExited.

As the handlers are triggered on the GridPane, moving the mouse over other element doesn't stop the feature.

With this I reduced the number of handler, simplified the code (As I do not need to manage extra behaviours as mover over another child).

Thanks !